# Webservice uploaded image url

Tags: java, web-services, image, upload

I am using java webservice (on tomcat).
I have the following code that handles image upload:

```
    public String uploadPicture(    long    xId,
                                int     pictureIndex,
                                String  imageData )
{
    File imageFile  = new File( new String( "D:\\" + xId + "_" + pictureIndex ) );

    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream    fos             = new FileOutputStream( imageFile );
        byte[]              encodedImage    = Base64.decode( imageData );

        fos.write( encodedImage );
        fos.close();
        return imageFile.getPath();
    } 
    catch( FileNotFoundException e ) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( Base64DecodingException e ) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch( IOException e ) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

1. I specify the path as D:\ since it is on the local PC.
   But I need to update it the the path on the server where it will be deployed - then should change it to ~\picDir? something like that?
2. The webservice url: http://192.168.0.11:8080/XWebService/services/XWebService
   will be updated to domain instead of the 192.168.0.11
   What should be the URL to get the image? (E.g. if the picture folder is: ~\picDir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If target server will run Linux/Unix, then proper path should be something like /usr/share/myapp. '~\' is totally wrong, I guess you meant '~/' which will point to home folder of current user. This should be avoided since you might run web server as different users with different home directories. Usually, on each environment (developer machine, demo, live server) you should have such place for storing configuration and data needed by an application.
2. File System location of your pictures has nothing to do with the URL under which photos will be located. It depends on Web Server (Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, etc.) which will run your application and your application itself. For instance, you can configure your Tomcat server to map domain www.myapp.com to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/ directory. Servlet which will publish images might take them from configuration dir mentioned in 1. = /usr/share/myapp/picDir. If the servlet can be accessed via /pictures?picId=1 then you will find them under www.myapp.com/pictures?picId=1. However, if you just want to put static images inside your *.war file to be accessed by the browser, put them in root directory of your *.war file.

To summarize:

1. Choose (and tell us) your application server
2. Use some configuration directory for all environments and configure your server to be able to see it
3. Configure your server for desired domain

You should read more about context of *.war files and how the file itself is being organised.

**Understanding URLs and context on example of Tomcat**

Assuming that:

1. On your local machine desired servlet is located under: http://localhost:8080/myapp/utils/myservlet.html
2. Your app is packed as myapp.war
3. Remote Tomcat has IP 2.2.2.2 and is running on port 8080

When you deploy your myapp.war to remote Tomcat into webapps directory (/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps) it will get unpacked and you will be able to see your servlet under http://2.2.2.2:8080/myapp/utils/myservlet.html. By configuring your application in Tomcat's server.xml you can add domain name and reduce unnecessary "myapp" part called context, effectively leaving URL in form of http://www.myapp.com/utils/myservlet.html. This is what you want in production environment. This topic is explained in Tomcat's documentation, please refer to it.

**Accessing File System resources from web application**
If you would like to save or get any file from your server, please keep in mind that client (Web Browser) has no idea about underlying disk structure. The browser uses request-response communication pattern which (in terms of upload/download) can be handled by server like this:

- upload - grab some byte content from Request and save it as a file on **server file system**
- download - read some byte content from **server file system** and stream it as a Response

As you can see in both cases **server file system** is internal concern of the server itself. You can save it anywhere you want. You can read bytes from whatever location. That is why it's good to have MYAPP_CONF (mentioned in comments) to store and read those files always from some predefined directory.

Comment: I am using tomcat server. Images are being uploaded by the user - not static.

Comment: Great, what we usually do is to create environmental variable which points to our configuration directory, let's say: MYAPP_CONF=/usr/share/tomcat6/myapp. When you are developing, then point MYAPP_CONF on your PC to 'D:\'. Put picDir under that directory. That way you will have the same configuration for development and production.
Please remember to make sure that Tomcat sees that variable, though.

When you need to access some files from servlet, use System.getProperty("MYAPP_CONF"), voila.

Comment: Thanks a lot.......................:) But if I want to D/L the image..... from which URL should I get it. I missed this part in your explanasion

Comment: Edited response. Hope that helps.